# What does a 'full 18×16 barrel shifter' mean?

Tags: multiplexer, circuit-design

My practical textbook asks me to design a **full 18×16 barrel shifter** on paper.
I have tried looking around but cannot seem to figure out what the *A×B* convention means when describing a barrel shifter.

Online resources describe a barrel shifter in terms of the total number of input/output bits (**n**) and sometimes also add a max shift capability (**k**). In most cases I have seen described, **n** is a power of 2 (2,4,8,16,...) while **k** is almost always equal to **n - 1**.

I could simply treat **n = 18**, **k = 16** here and implement a left shift-only, *4* stages of *18* `2:1` MUXs each, but that'd be cumbersome and/or incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

I also found it hard to find a concise description of this notation. However, by plugging in some different values for n and k in Google searches for "n x k barrel shifter", I was able to find [this PDF](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece410/salem/files/s14/lectures/Chapt11_Figures.pdf), which shows an 8x4 barrel shifter on page 27, where there are 8 inputs and 4 outputs.

I'm not entirely sure what the value of an asymmetric barrel shifter would be, except perhaps just cost savings for a very specific implementation or device. They seem to be hard to find information about.

If you are in a class, I would ask your instructor or TA about what the correct interpretation is. The only resource I can find suggests it's inputs x outputs, but I think inputs x shift capability is a reasonable interpretation as well.